# should my 4 prong electric range outlet circuit effect a 15 amp. GFI kitchen lighting breaker?

Tags: electrical

should my 4 prong electric range outlet circuit effect a 15 amp. GFI kitchen lighting breaker? I am a 2009 retired electrician and the codes may have changed but I have not ever heard of this type of outlet to require GFI protection. Proper grounding and or internal GFI protection should be provided by the range circuits. The range does not have a convenience connection on it; all low voltage circuits are internal.

Comment: What does "effect" mean in your question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be more explicit about what you're asking. What kind of "effect" are you seeing? Where are the breakers in the panel in relation to each other? Do you _have_ a GFCI breaker for the range? If so, I'd agree that seems odd, but it's not clear from your question. Your question is getting votes to close it - don't take it personally if it gets closed, you can still edit a closed question, and with clarity it will, I'm sure, be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

A 4-wire range connection should not require GFCI since it has a *bona fide* ground separate and isolated from neutral.

Many ranges are *still* shipped wired with 3-prong cables, despite 3-prong sockets being outlawed in 1996.  The 3-prong configuration has a jumper to tie the range's chassis to the neutral wire (!!!)... and yes, this would be bootlegging ground if you did it anywhere else. **It is important that bootleg jumper be removed with a 4-wire connection!** It is often overlooked.

No range ever requires GFCI, but there's a case to be made for GFCI when the wiring in the walls lacks a ground.  In that case a 4-wire socket should be used, and marked "GFCI Protected / No Equipment Ground" per 406.4(D)(2) and 110.3(b)->8(c).

Range circuits are not supposed to be tied to 120V electrical circuits in any way, since 40-50A circuits must be dedicated to 1 equipment (except for range circuits which can serve multiple ranges and ovens, but nothing else).  Also 15A receps are not allowed on 40/50A circuits.

However, the 15A circuit is connected to the range circuit *at the panel main buses*, obviously.  A lost "hot" wire from the utility will cause 120V loads on that phase to fail, unless a 240V load is turned on. The 240V load won't work well, but will partially "power up" 120V loads on the dead phase. A very common sign of that is dead kitchen circuits that mysteriously resurrect when a burner is turned on!

It will also seemingly fix itself randomly.  What's actually happening is the water heater is cycling on and off.  All the 240V loads (paralleled) are in series with all the 120V loads on the dead phase (paralleled).